# How can I get the user who reposted a track from the /me/activities api endpoint?

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I'm using the /me/activities api endpoint to pull a logged in user's dashboard (feed). The response has all of the tracks from the dashboard (including those of type "track-repost") however it doesn't seem to contain the user who actually reposted the track. Is there any way to get this information?